# How to turn off daemon gradle in pipeline using sonarqube?

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I woud like to run my project with sonarqube launching it to pipeline.
This is Android project but there are some problems with gradle daemon.
From the local project I can set daemon to false in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

But after pushing my repo I see daemon still works. How to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `--no-daemon` option to your gradle command. I'm assuming you are doing something similar to:

```
./gradlew clean build sonar -x test -Dsonar.login="$SONARQUBE_LOGIN_SECRET" -Dsonar.host.url="$SONARQUBE_HOST_URL" --info --no-daemon
```

I've added `--no-daemon` at the end as an example.